# How to kill off a program with cin.fail()

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to make a condition so that if the user inputs anything besides an integer the program will terminate. Whenever I put let's say the letter A the program repeatedly outputs zero. I think its exit() thats the issue but when I substitute it I have the same problem. Advice?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;
void even(int);
void odd(int);
int main()
{
    int i;
    do{
        cout << "Enter an integer" << endl;
        cin >> i;
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            even(i);
        else if (i % 2 == 1)
            odd(i);
        else if (cin.fail())
            exit (0);
    }while(!isdigit(i));

    return (0);
}
void even(int i)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
void odd (int i)
{
    //nothing here
}
```

Comment: `else if (cin.fail())` -> `if (!cin)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `cin >> i` fails, the variable `i` is not assigned.  In your program, this means it still has an indeterminate value.  Using an indeterminate value as in `(i % 2 == 0)` is undefined behavior, meaning as far as the C++ Standard is concerned, anything could happen.

On most common systems, though, the variable `i` will have some value, whatever was left over from the last time some register or piece of memory was used.  This value will be either even or odd.  So if `i` happens to be zero or positive, your `fail` check will never be reached.

You will probably want to reorder your `if` checks to check `cin` first, and only use `i` if the extraction was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a little tweak in your program should solve the issue for you :

```
if (cin.fail())
            exit (0);
        else if(i % 2 == 0)
            even(i);
        else if (i % 2 == 1)
            odd(i);
```